# how can I select three tables with join in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

[image: relation]

I want join this tables in only query mysql, I'm trying but it doesn't work.

I want get by idtravel as this pseudocode:

```
select * 
from travel t
left join user 
left join vehicule
where idtravel = ?

select * 
from
    (select * 
     from vehicle v
     left join user u on v.user_idv= u.id
  
select * 
from travel t
left join user u on t.user_idt= u.id) as res
```

Comment: What's the point of the outer joins? Do you want **all users** but only travel records for `id=whatever`? Or  just the **subset of users** which match travel records where `id=whatever`? It's difficult for us to reverse-engineer your business rules from pseudo-code. So please explain the logic you want to implement. Or provide some sample input data and expected output derived from that sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from travel t 
left join `user` u on u.id = t.user_idt
left join vehicle v on u.id = v.user_idv
where t.idtravel = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user.*, vehicle.name as vehicale_name, travel.* FROM user 
left join `vehicle` on vehicle.user_id = user.id
left join `travel` on travel.user_id = user.id
where travel.idtravel = ?
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: See in code there is all information display from user table because there is user.*  that's why and others information from the rest of the tables.

-> user_id is available in vehicle & travel table so User table is the parent table
-> and in the above code join with child tables where user_id available and make the condition where travel.idtravel = ? 

-> ? measn you can useany idtravel like 1,2 etc.

Comment: Please **edit your answer** to improve it. The comments section is for, er, *comments*. A comment is something which can be deleted without detracting from the post it's commenting on.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM user u
LEFT JOIN travel t ON u.id = t.user_idt 
LEFT JOIN vehicle v ON u.id = v.user_idv 
WHERE t.idtravel = ?;
```

Comment: Explain your code little bit for better understanding. Welcome to stackoverflow